# MS Access 2013, Subform operations destroy the class module

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in my Access project called `MainForm`, there is a sub form called `subForm`, also many buttons on the `MainForm`, at the same time, I created a class module to handle the `OnClick` event for all the buttons and the module name is `classButtons`.

Code in the class module:

```
Public WithEvents cButtons as Access.CommandButton

Dim tmpValue as String

Private Sub cButtons_Click()
    Select Case cButton.Name
        Case "ButtonA"
            MainForm.subForm.Requery
        Case "ButtonB"
            Let tmpValue = subForm.ComboBox1.Value
            DoCmd.RunSQL "update sometable set somefield='" & tmpValue & "'"
        Case "ButtonC"
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUnhideColumns
    End Select
End Sub
```

In the `Open` event of the `MainForm`, I have the following code:

```
For i = 0 to Me.Controls.Count - 1
    If Left(Me.Controls(i).Name,6) = "cmdbtn" Then
        set btnClass = New classButtons
        set btnClass.cButtons = Me.Controls(i)
        btnClass.cButtons.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
        mdPublic.buttonColl.Add btnClass 'buttonColl is a collection variable declared in another module called "mdPublic"
    End If
Next
```

Then once the `MainForm` is opened, all the 3 buttons works well, but once ButtonA or ButtonB is clicked, all the 3 buttons will stop working.

I tried to remove the `subForm` operations from ButtonA and ButtonB, and found that the problem is disappeared, so I guess the `subForm` operations just "destroy" the class module.

But I do need those operations, anyone has any ideas? Thank you !!!!!

Comment: Sorry I didn't do enough test before I post this question, the truth is:
Not only the subform, even if I tried to get a value from a ComboBox on the mainform, or just requery the mainform,  it will destroy the class module too. Then I tried to create a new blank project, everything works well, back to my current project, not working again. The only differences between the two projects are the Tables, but I don't think the data in a table would have any effect on the class module, it's driving nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is make a function behind the form to handle the button behaviors, call it HandleButtonClick(x As String), then in each button Click event property:

=HandleButtonClick("ButtonA") -- change the button designation as appropriate

Also, I always name a subform container different from the subform it holds, such as ctrDetails. Code behind main form must reference the subform container name.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, function is one of the back up solutions, if i couldn't solve this issue, i will give it up and start to use function.
As for the subform, the `subForm` is just an example, I did set a different name for the container.